# JAXB parsing a wrapper class which contains a single string property

Tags: java, jaxb

The xml structure I am trying to parse is:

```
<contentFiles>
<contentFile>
<fileNumbers>
    <fileNumber>123<fileNumber>
</fileNumbers>
</contentFile>
<contentFile/>
<contentFiles>
```

How do I parse this using JAXB ?

I used the annotations on getters described above but I only get the last element in the multiples of FileNumbers saved. I want to save all the elements of FileNumbers in the list. How do I do this ?

EDIT:::

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "contentFiles")
public class RtSuperQuickMetadata
{
    private List<RtSuperQuickMetadataItem> rtSuperQuickMetadataItems;

    @XmlElement(name = "contentFile")
    public final List<RtSuperQuickMetadataItem> getRtSuperQuickMetadataItems()
    {
        return rtSuperQuickMetadataItems;
    }
// Setter
}


public class RtSuperQuickMetadataItem 
{


private List<FileNumber> fileNumbers;
public RtSuperQuickMetadataItem()
{
  fileNumbers = new ArrayList<FileNumber>();
}

@XmlElement(name = "fileNumbers")
public List<FileNumber> getFileNumbers()
{
    return fileNumbers;
}
//setter
}


@XmlRootElement(name="fileNumber")
public class FileNumber
{
    private String fileNumber;

    /**
     * Default no-arg constructor.
     */
    public FileNumber()
    {
        // public no-arg constructor for JAXB
    }

    /**
     * Accept a filenumber as constructor arg.
     * @param fileNumber is the fileNumber
     */
    public FileNumber(final String fileNumber)
    {
        this.fileNumber = fileNumber;
    }

    /**
     * Getter.
     * @return the fileNumber
     */
    //@XmlElement(name = "fileNumber")
    public final String getFileNumber()
    {
        return fileNumber;
    }

    /**
     * Setter.
     * @param fileNumber to be set.
     */
    public final void setFileNumber(final String fileNumber)
    {
        this.fileNumber = fileNumber;
    }

    @Override
    public final String toString()
    {
        return fileNumber;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the faulty code? The code that only gets you the last element? An [sscce](http://sscce.org) would be best.

Comment: One problem I see is that you have a class name, FileNumber, that has a the same element name as a property, fileNumber, and that your JAXB file will need to nest these two elements.

Comment: What must remain constant here -- your Java class structure or the XML file structure?

Comment: I changed the property name to just number and on the getter i said @XmlRootElement(name="fileNumber") but this problem doesn't go away

Comment: Please show a larger typical and *valid* XML file. And get rid of the FileNumber class. Instead use a `List<String>` so you don't have to nest the fileNumber String element inside of the fileNumber class element.

Comment: Sorry corrected it. Yes I will do that. but wanted to know why code doesnt work ..

Comment: Did you solve your problem? If so, consider posting your solution as an answer, and please flag me as I'd be interested to see what you did!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason I'm asking for a larger XML file representation is that your code will completely depend on the requirements of the XML file. For instance, this bit of your code works with the following XML file:

Code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class JaxbTest {

   private static final String RESOURCE_NAME = "data.txt";

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      // marshallTest();

      unmarshallTest();
   }

   private static void unmarshallTest() {
      JAXBContext context;
      try {
         context = JAXBContext.newInstance(RtSuperQuickMetadata.class);
         Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
         RtSuperQuickMetadata metaData = (RtSuperQuickMetadata) unmarshaller
               .unmarshal(JaxbTest.class.getResourceAsStream(RESOURCE_NAME));
         System.out.println(metaData);
      } catch (JAXBException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }

   private static void marshallTest() {
      RtSuperQuickMetadata data = new RtSuperQuickMetadata();
      List<RtSuperQuickMetadataItem> metaItemList = new ArrayList<RtSuperQuickMetadataItem>();
      RtSuperQuickMetadataItem metaDataItem = new RtSuperQuickMetadataItem();
      List<FileNumber> fileNumbers = new ArrayList<FileNumber>();
      fileNumbers.add(new FileNumber("123"));
      fileNumbers.add(new FileNumber("124"));
      fileNumbers.add(new FileNumber("125"));
      fileNumbers.add(new FileNumber("126"));
      metaDataItem.setFileNumbers(fileNumbers);
      metaItemList.add(metaDataItem);
      data.setRtSuperQuickMetadataItems(metaItemList);
      JAXBContext context;
      try {
         context = JAXBContext.newInstance(RtSuperQuickMetadata.class);
         Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
         marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

         marshaller.marshal(data, System.out);

      } catch (JAXBException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}

@XmlRootElement(name = "contentFiles")
class RtSuperQuickMetadata {
   private List<RtSuperQuickMetadataItem> rtSuperQuickMetadataItems;

   @XmlElement(name = "contentFile")
   public final List<RtSuperQuickMetadataItem> getRtSuperQuickMetadataItems() {
      return rtSuperQuickMetadataItems;
   }

   public void setRtSuperQuickMetadataItems(
         List<RtSuperQuickMetadataItem> rtSuperQuickMetadataItems) {
      this.rtSuperQuickMetadataItems = rtSuperQuickMetadataItems;
   }

   @Override
   public String toString() {
      return "RtSuperQuickMetadata [rtSuperQuickMetadataItems="
            + rtSuperQuickMetadataItems + "]";
   }

}

class RtSuperQuickMetadataItem {

   private List<FileNumber> fileNumbers;

   public RtSuperQuickMetadataItem() {
      fileNumbers = new ArrayList<FileNumber>();
   }

   @XmlElement(name = "fileNumbers")
   public List<FileNumber> getFileNumbers() {
      return fileNumbers;
   }

   public void setFileNumbers(List<FileNumber> fileNumbers) {
      this.fileNumbers = fileNumbers;
   }

   @Override
   public String toString() {
      return "RtSuperQuickMetadataItem [fileNumbers=" + fileNumbers + "]";
   }

}

@XmlRootElement(name = "fileNumber")
class FileNumber {
   private String fileNumber;

   public FileNumber() {}

   public FileNumber(final String fileNumber) {
      this.fileNumber = fileNumber;
   }

   // @XmlElement(name = "fileNumber")
   public final String getFileNumber() {
      return fileNumber;
   }

   public final void setFileNumber(final String fileNumber) {
      this.fileNumber = fileNumber;
   }

   @Override
   public final String toString() {
      return fileNumber;
   }
}
```

The xml file, assuming it's in the same directory as your class files:
jaxbTest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<contentFiles>
    <contentFile>
        <fileNumbers>
            <fileNumber>123</fileNumber>
        </fileNumbers>
        <fileNumbers>
            <fileNumber>124</fileNumber>
        </fileNumbers>
        <fileNumbers>
            <fileNumber>125</fileNumber>
        </fileNumbers>
        <fileNumbers>
            <fileNumber>126</fileNumber>
        </fileNumbers>
    </contentFile>
</contentFiles>
```

However if this is not your desired XML structure, then the code must change.

---

**Edit**
If you want to not nest each fileNumber element in a fileNumbers element, then get rid of the FileNumbers class and instead use a `List<String>` with the `@XmlElementWrapper` annotation.

```
@XmlElementWrapper(name = "fileNumbers")
@XmlElement(name = "fileNumber")
public List<String> getFileNumbers() {
   return fileNumbers;
}
```

For instance please check out this code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class JaxbTest {

   private static final String RESOURCE_NAME = "data.xml";

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      // marshallTest();
      unmarshallTest();
   }

   private static void unmarshallTest() {
      JAXBContext context;
      try {
         context = JAXBContext.newInstance(RtSuperQuickMetadata.class);
         Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
         RtSuperQuickMetadata metaData = (RtSuperQuickMetadata) unmarshaller
               .unmarshal(JaxbTest.class.getResourceAsStream(RESOURCE_NAME));
         System.out.println(metaData);
      } catch (JAXBException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }

   private static void marshallTest() {
      RtSuperQuickMetadata data = new RtSuperQuickMetadata();
      List<RtSuperQuickMetadataItem> metaItemList = new ArrayList<RtSuperQuickMetadataItem>();
      RtSuperQuickMetadataItem metaDataItem = new RtSuperQuickMetadataItem();
      // List<FileNumber> fileNumbers = new ArrayList<FileNumber>();
      // fileNumbers.add(new FileNumber("123"));
      // fileNumbers.add(new FileNumber("124"));
      // fileNumbers.add(new FileNumber("125"));
      // fileNumbers.add(new FileNumber("126"));

      List<String> fileNumbers = new ArrayList<String>();
      fileNumbers.add("123");
      fileNumbers.add("124");
      fileNumbers.add("125");
      fileNumbers.add("126");

      metaDataItem.setFileNumbers(fileNumbers);
      metaItemList.add(metaDataItem);
      data.setRtSuperQuickMetadataItems(metaItemList);
      JAXBContext context;
      try {
         context = JAXBContext.newInstance(RtSuperQuickMetadata.class);
         Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
         marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

         marshaller.marshal(data, System.out);

      } catch (JAXBException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}

@XmlRootElement(name = "contentFiles")
class RtSuperQuickMetadata {
   private List<RtSuperQuickMetadataItem> rtSuperQuickMetadataItems;

   @XmlElement(name = "contentFile")
   public final List<RtSuperQuickMetadataItem> getRtSuperQuickMetadataItems() {
      return rtSuperQuickMetadataItems;
   }

   public void setRtSuperQuickMetadataItems(
         List<RtSuperQuickMetadataItem> rtSuperQuickMetadataItems) {
      this.rtSuperQuickMetadataItems = rtSuperQuickMetadataItems;
   }

   @Override
   public String toString() {
      return "RtSuperQuickMetadata [rtSuperQuickMetadataItems="
            + rtSuperQuickMetadataItems + "]";
   }

}

class RtSuperQuickMetadataItem {

   private List<String> fileNumbers;

   public RtSuperQuickMetadataItem() {
      fileNumbers = new ArrayList<String>();
   }

   @XmlElementWrapper(name = "fileNumbers")
   @XmlElement(name = "fileNumber")
   public List<String> getFileNumbers() {
      return fileNumbers;
   }

   public void setFileNumbers(List<String> fileNumbers) {
      this.fileNumbers = fileNumbers;
   }

   @Override
   public String toString() {
      return "RtSuperQuickMetadataItem [fileNumbers=" + fileNumbers + "]";
   }

}
```

Will work with this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<contentFiles>
    <contentFile>
        <fileNumbers>
            <fileNumber>123</fileNumber>
            <fileNumber>124</fileNumber>
            <fileNumber>125</fileNumber>
            <fileNumber>126</fileNumber>
        </fileNumbers>
    </contentFile>
</contentFiles>
```

Comment: It doesn't have multiple fileNumbers tags .. just multiples of fileNumber nested within one fileNumbers

Comment: Then get rid of the FileNumbers class -- use a `List<String>`

Comment: @Phoenix: please see edit to my answer, and in particular my use of the `@XmlElementWrapper` annotation.

Comment: Thanks Hovercraft, with Strings it does work .. i wanted to know if we can make it work with List<FileNumber> though ..

Comment: @Phoenix: I've already put about 2 hours into this thing, and my current code does work, so if you want to make things more difficult, I will leave that effort to you I think. Although it does beg the question in my mind -- why? What is your motivation behind making it more difficult?

Comment: @Phoenix: my guess is that you would need to use an [XmlAdapter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/XmlAdapter.html) of some sorts for this. Have at it and good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I've done JAX-B but I think this should do the trick (only relevant sections posted).  If you want to avoid creating the FileNumberList class you can probably do so with an adapter but that will be more work than it is worth.

```
public class RtSuperQuickMetadataItem {

    @XmlElement
    public FileNumberList getFileNumbers() {

    }

}

public class FileNumberList {

    @XmlElement(name="fileNumber")
    public List<String> getList() {

    }

}
```

Comment: To avoid creating a FileNumberList class, simply use the XmlElementWrapper annotation; a custom adapter is not needed.